# Plot crosstable information

Tags: r, crosstab

I have a dataframe `likes`:

```
    Gender   Like  
    male     yes    
    female   no  
    female   yes
    other    yes
    male     no
    male     no
    female   no  
    female   yes
    other    no
    male     no
    male     yes
```

Based on this dataframe, I would like to draw a histogram that specifies each gender and the number of 'yes'and 'no' per gender (see picture)

[image]

If I use `table(likes)`, I get a table that specifies the number of yes' and no's per gender. However, if I use `plot(table(likes))`, I get a really strange plot that is hard to interpret.

What can I do, to get such output?

Comment: Something like: `ggplot(likes, aes(Gender, fill = Like)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")`

Comment: hi try `sjp.grpfrq` from `sjplot` package  http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/reference/sjp.grpfrq.html

Comment: Or perhaps https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html

Comment: Not exactly related, but that's a bar chart, not a histogram. A histogram is a specific type of chart that shows a continuous distribution.

Comment: Calling `plot` on a `table` object gets a mosaic plot. See `?plot.table`: "This is a method of the generic plot function for (contingency) table objects. Whereas for two- and more dimensional tables, a mosaicplot is drawn, one-dimensional ones are plotted as bars."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this-

```
ggplot(data = dt) +
  aes(x = Gender, fill = Like) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  theme_minimal() +   
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat='count',position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

Output-

[image]

If you want `Like` as your `labels` then use this-

```
ggplot(data = dt) +
  aes(x = Gender, fill = Like) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlGnBu") +
  theme_minimal() +   
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(Like)),stat='count',position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

**Output 2-**

[image]